# Hive on AWS: convert S3 JSON to Columnar preserving partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, emr, amazon-emr, amazon-athena

I have files in S3 that contain many lines of JSON (separated by newline).  I want to convert these files to a Columnar Format for consumption by [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/)

I am following the [Converting to Columnar Formats guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html) to do this, however when converted to ORC, the partition convention in S3 is lost.

In this example, how do you preserve the `dt` partition in the converted to parquet s3 folder structure? When I run the example it just outputs `s3://myBucket/pq/000000_0` and NOT `s3://myBucket/pq/dt=2009-04-14-04-05/000000_0`

Here is the HQL that sets up interface to bring JSON into a Hive table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE impressions (
  requestBeginTime string,
  adId string,
  impressionId string,
  referrer string,
  userAgent string,
  userCookie string,
  ip string,
  number string,
  processId string,
  browserCookie string,
  requestEndTime string,
  timers struct<modelLookup:string, requestTime:string>,
  threadId string,
  hostname string,
  sessionId string)
PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
ROW FORMAT  serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
with serdeproperties ( 'paths'='requestBeginTime, adId, impressionId, referrer, userAgent, userCookie, ip' )
LOCATION 's3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/tables/impressions' ;
msck repair table impressions;
```

Here is the HQL that converts to Parquet

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  parquet_hive (
  requestBeginTime string,
  adId string,
  impressionId string,
  referrer string,
  userAgent string,
  userCookie string,
  ip string)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/pq/';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE parquet_hive SELECT requestbegintime,adid,impressionid,referrer,useragent,usercookie,ip FROM impressions where dt='2009-04-14-04-05';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Add `PARTITIONED BY (dt string)` to `parquet_hive` definition.

Second -
If you want to insert the data, partition by partition, you have to declare the partition you are inserting into. 
Note the `PARTITION (dt='2009-04-14-04-05')`

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE parquet_hive PARTITION (dt='2009-04-14-04-05')
SELECT requestbegintime,adid,impressionid,referrer,useragent,usercookie,ip 
FROM   impressions where dt='2009-04-14-04-05'
;
```

An easier way would be to use dynamic partitioning.
Note the `PARTITION (dt)` and the `dt` as a last column in in the SELECT.

You might need to to set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

---

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE parquet_hive PARTITION (dt)
SELECT requestbegintime,adid,impressionid,referrer,useragent,usercookie,ip,dt 
FROM   impressions where dt='2009-04-14-04-05'
;
```

P.s.
`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE impressions` does not "reads the JSON into a Hive table".
It is just an interface with the necessary information to read the HDFS files.
`

Comment: Really appreciate it thanks.  On AWS EMR running Hive 2.1.1 `set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;` is indeed required.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include the same `PARTITIONED BY (dt string)` parameter that is in your first statement, which will create the same directory structure.

In this case, the `dt` field (presumably, date) is actually stored in the directory name. A separate directory is created for each value.